# Git integration in Visual Studio not working as expected

Tags: git, visual-studio

I just installed GIT, everything is working fine when I use TortoiseGit. After doing a clone when I go into Visual Studio 2013, I have over 2000 files marked as modified, when I do a compare I see that the files are identical. Not sure if this is relevant, but these files seem to be mostly CSS files and images. What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Probably you have a git EOL (End Of Line) configuration issue

Comment: Could you post some screenshots?